# Why is this Swift code slower than a Delphi implementation?

Tags: performance, delphi, swift

Apple touted about the fast performance compared to other languages.  I never doubted this until recently when I began to write some code in Swift.

I implemented the xorshift algorithm in Swift, just to find that the Swift version is about 80 times slower than Delphi.

Xorshift is described at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift

SWIFT version:

```swift
// xcrun -sdk macosx10.10 swiftc main.swift
import Foundation

func xor_shift(x0: UInt32, y0: UInt32, z0: UInt32, w0: UInt32) -> () -> UInt32 {
    var x = x0
    var y = y0
    var z = z0
    var w = w0

    func num() -> UInt32 {
        let t = x ^ (x << 11)
        x = y
        y = z
        z = w
        w = w ^ (w >> 19) ^ (t ^ (t >> 8))
        return w
    }

    return num
}


let loopcount = Int32.max
let xrand = xor_shift(2014, 12, 29, 2015)
let t0  = NSDate()

for _ in 0..<loopcount {
    xrand()
}

let t1 = NSDate()
let ms = Int(t1.timeIntervalSinceDate(t0) * 1000)
println("[SWIFT] Time used: \(ms) millisecons, Loop count: \(loopcount)")
```

Delphi/Pascal version:

```pascal
// Command line compile:
// dcc64  xortest.dpr

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
program xortest;
uses sysutils;

type
  TRandSeed = record
    x,y,z,w: UInt32;
  end;

function xrand(var seed: TRandSeed): UInt32;
var
  t: UInt32;
begin
    t := seed.x xor (seed.x shl 11);
    seed.x := seed.y; seed.y := seed.z; seed.z := seed.w;
    seed.w := seed.w xor (seed.w shr 19) xor (t xor (t shr 8));
  result := seed.w
end;

var
  r: TRandSeed;
  t0, t1: TDateTime;
  s: string;
  i, loopcount: integer;
begin
  // Set the rand seed
  r.x := 2014;  r.y := 12;  r.z := 29;  r.w := 2015;

  loopcount := high(Int32);
  t0 := now;
  for i := 1 to loopcount do xrand(r);
  t1 := now;

  s := Format('[PASCAL] Time used: %d milliseconds, Loopcount = %d', [Trunc((t1-t0)*24*3600*1000), loopcount]);
  writeln(s);
end.
```

Test environments:

1. OS X: iMac 27" retina 4 GHz Intel Core i7
2. Windows 7 run inside VMWare fusion on the above-mentioned iMac

The Swift version outputs:
  [SWIFT] Time used: 412568 millisecons, Loop count: 2147483647

The Pascal version outputs:
  [PASCAL] Time used: 5083 milliseconds, Loopcount = 2147483647

The Pascal version runs 81 times faster than the Swift version, not to mention that the former runs inside a virtual machine.
Is Apple lying about the fast performance of Swift, or is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: Swift if fairly slow, when using it with the 'Debug' build configuration, have you ran it with the 'Release' build configuration? Also you can change the optimisation from the projects 'Build Settings -> Apple LLVM - Code generation' to -0fast for the fastest run.

Comment: Just recompiled using the suggested settings, and it did run much faster but still 23 times slower than the Pascal version:  [SWIFT] Time used: 114522 millisecons, Loop count: 2147483647

Comment: I belive the biggest cause for performance difference here is the fact that the two presented code samples does not use same implementation. For instance in SWIFT you use four variables (x, y, z, w) but in Delphi you put all these into same record. I belive that using record on Delphi part may reduce the number of stack operations as it is posible that the whole record is put into stack at the same time, while using four variables would probably not result in all four of them of being in stack at the same time. And this would result in greater number of stack operations and slower performance.

Comment: So if you realy want to comapare speeds athleast make sure that you use same implementation and as litle of language "candies".

Answer (score 9):

edit: oops, sorry, I mistranslated part of the Delphi code, so not quite as good as a constant calculation  – but the closure is definitely the problem so you should re-run your comparison against it as it makes a dramatic difference.

Your Swift code is not a direct translation of your Delphi code, so you are not comparing apples to apples.  In the Swift version, you are calling a function that returns a closure that captures some variables, then calling that closure.  Whereas in the Delphi version, you are just calling a function that takes a struct.  Below is a more direct Swift translation of the Delphi code.

Closures can often be a barrier to compiler optimization.  Removing this barrier seems to help the code a lot, since if I run my Swift equivalent after compiling with `-O`, it calculates 2,147,483,647 runs of `xrand` in <s>0 milliseconds</s> 5,341 milliseconds, compared to 238,762 milliseconds for the version with the closure on my horrible ancient laptop.

Why?  Because without that barrier to optimization, the compiler has way more latitude to rewrite the code to be as fast as possible.  <s>Possibly even replaces the entire function with a constant value</s> (it's also possible that it could detect the value is not even being used, and so not run the function at all, which is why I added a store of the result and printout of the result just to be sure).

```swift
import Foundation

struct TRandSeed {
    var x: UInt32
    var y: UInt32
    var z: UInt32
    var w: UInt32
}

func xrand(inout seed: TRandSeed) -> UInt32{
    var t = seed.x ^ (seed.x << 11)
    seed.x = seed.y
    seed.y = seed.z
    seed.z = seed.w
    seed.w = seed.w ^ (seed.w >> 19) ^ (t ^ (t >> 8))
    return seed.w
}

var r = TRandSeed(x: 2014, y: 12, z: 29, w: 2015)

let loopcount = Int32.max-1
let t0  = NSDate()

for _ in 0..<loopcount {
    xrand(&r)
}
let result = xrand(&r)

let t1 = NSDate()
let ms = Int(t1.timeIntervalSinceDate(t0) * 1000)
println("[SWIFT] Time used: \(ms) millisecons to calculate \(result), Loop count: \(loopcount+1)")
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the cause of the problem. Yes, it's the closure that caused this problem.  BTW, the seed parameter should be declared as inout:  func xrand(inout seed: TRandSeed)

Comment: yup sorry about that, I mistook Delphi's `var` for something like Swift's.  Be interested in the new comparison benchmark.

Comment: @SimonLau can you post the new times please?

Answer (score 0):

I slightly modified the code by Airspeed Velocity:

```swift
import Foundation

struct TRandSeed {
    var x: UInt32
    var y: UInt32
    var z: UInt32
    var w: UInt32
}

func xrand(inout seed: TRandSeed) -> UInt32{
    let t = seed.x ^ (seed.x << 11)
    seed.x = seed.y
    seed.y = seed.z
    seed.z = seed.w
    seed.w = seed.w ^ (seed.w >> 19) ^ (t ^ (t >> 8))
    return seed.w
}

var r = TRandSeed(x: 2014, y: 12, z: 29, w: 2015)

let loopcount = Int32.max

let t0  = NSDate()
var total: UInt64 = 0

for _ in 0..<loopcount {
    let t = xrand(&r)
    total = total &+ UInt64(t)
}

let t1 = NSDate()
let ms = Int(t1.timeIntervalSinceDate(t0) * 1000)
println("[SWIFT] Time used: \(ms) milliseconds to calculate, Loop count: \(loopcount),  Total = \(total)")
```

I compiled it with the command line: xcrun -sdk macosx10.10 swiftc -O main.swift

The new code outputs:  [SWIFT] Time used: 2838 milliseconds to calculate, Loop count: 2147483647,  Total = 4611723097222874280

The performance is now up to par.  (Since the Pascal version runs inside a virtual machine, it's not fair to say the Swift binary is twice faster.)

Comment: So when Swift underperforms Delphi, Apple are "lying about performance", whereas when a Delphi underperforms Swift, "it's not fair" to make comparisons?  :-)